# Ifelse statement syntax multiple conditions is broken

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having some trouble with a nested ifelse statement. I have the following code written. It should force a TRUE or FALSE  but I am getting some NAs. Can you help me figure out where its broken?

data looks something like...

```
Name<- c(Jon,Jim,Jake,Jess,Jill,Jay,Jason)
LinkFlag<- c( NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA)
1<- c(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
2<- c(2.5,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, 3.0,  NA)

spread_wide<-c(Name,LinkFlag,1,2)
```

The intended Result is that there are no NAs

```
sw_RESULTS$EvalSeq1to2<-ifelse(spread_wide$`1` == 99, TRUE, 
                   ifelse(spread_wide$`1` == (spread_wide$`2`-1), TRUE,  
                           ifelse(is.na(spread_wide$`2`),TRUE,   
                                       ifelse(spread_wide$`2` ==99,TRUE,
                                            ifelse(spread_wide$`1`== (spread_wide$`2`-0.5),TRUE, 
                                                       ifelse(spread_wide$`1` == spread_wide$`2`, TRUE,  
                                                                   ifelse(spread_wide$`LinkFlag`=='FlagforSkip", TRUE,
                                                                                                                                 FALSE)))))))
```

Comment: why not to use Switch statement instead? and if you want to use if else give some space between them like if else ... , and use right syntax of 'if { } else if {}' as 'ifelse ifelse' is not a right syntax

Comment: Lots of nested `ifelse` statements is usually going to result in errors that are hard to track down. It would be better to update your question with a description of what you're trying to achieve, as there will undoubtedly be a better way to do this .

Comment: @Aaqib `ifelse` is a convenience function in R, so the syntax is not an issue, but yea, that many nested `ifelse`'s is probably not a good idea.

Comment: @useR will keep an eye on ifelse next time.

Comment: What is this `1<- c(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`? And `spread_wide<-c(Name,LinkFlag,1,2)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas - an attempt to make a `data.frame` I assume. Like `Name<- c("Jon","Jim","Jake","Jess","Jill","Jay","Jason");
LinkFlag<- c( NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA);
\`1\` <- c(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
\`2\` <- c(2.5,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, 3.0,  NA);
spread_wide<- data.frame(Name,LinkFlag,\`1\`,\`2\`,check.names=FALSE)` I imagine.

Comment: @thelatemail So the code is broken long before the nested `ifelse`...

Answer (score 2):

You essentially have a set of binary checks that each return `TRUE`, or `FALSE` if none of them are true. So, it's simple then to just make a `matrix` or `list` of all the checks together:

```
checks <- with(spread_wide,
  cbind(
    `1` == 99,
    `1` == `2` - 1,
    is.na(`2`),
    `2` == 99,
    `1` == (`2` - 0.5),
    `1` == `2`,
    LinkFlag == 'FlagforSkip'
  )
)

rowSums(checks, na.rm=TRUE) > 0
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

The secret to the final line is using the `na.rm=TRUE` so that you are never giving any consideration to comparisons like `NA == 1` which will return `NA` instead of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

As a side-note, using variable names like `1` or `2` is just asking for trouble.

---

Reproducible data that works:

```
Name<- c("Jon","Jim","Jake","Jess","Jill","Jay","Jason")
LinkFlag<- c( NA,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, NA, NA)
`1` <- c(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
`2` <- c(2.5,  NA,  NA,  NA,  NA, 3.0,  NA)
spread_wide<- data.frame(Name,LinkFlag,`1`,`2`,check.names=FALSE)
```